# Azure Powershell - Switch-AzureMode error in version 1

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Hello I am not powershell programmer and I learning right now using pluralsight and exericese file giving me error and I think it happening because or version change of Azure Powershell from 0.9.8 to version 1.0

Here is error :

```
c:\Pluralsight\chef\2-chef> .\Create-CourseEnvironmentARM.ps1
Switch-AzureMode : The term 'Switch-AzureMode' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Pluralsight\chef\2-chef\Create-CourseEnvironmentARM.ps1:28 char:1
+ Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Switch-AzureMode:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Test-AzureResourceGroup : The term 'Test-AzureResourceGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Pluralsight\chef\2-chef\Create-CourseEnvironmentARM.ps1:32 char:5
+ if((Test-AzureResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $GroupName) -eq $false){
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-AzureResourceGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment : The term 'New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Pluralsight\chef\2-chef\Create-CourseEnvironmentARM.ps1:44 char:1
+ New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

File Name :.\Create-CourseEnvironmentARM.ps1

> I was searching error in google and confirm that azure power shell
>   deprecate function "Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager -Verbose"

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Deprecation-of-Switch-AzureMode-in-Azure-PowerShell

Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager -Verbose

Here is code from Create-CourseEnvironmentARM.ps1

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager -Verbose

### Create Resource Group ###

if((Test-AzureResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $GroupName) -eq $false){
    New-AzureResourceGroup -Name $GroupName -Location $Location -Verbose
    $ResourceGroup = Get-AzureResourceGroup -Name $GroupName
    }
    else {$ResourceGroup = Get-AzureResourceGroup -Name $GroupName}

$parameters = @{
    'newStorageAccountName'="$StorageName";
    'adminUsername'="$AdminUsername";
    'dnsNameForPublicIP'="$PublicDNSName"
    }

New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment `
    -Name $DeploymentName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName `
    -TemplateFile azuredeploy.json `
    -TemplateParameterObject $parameters `
    -Verbose
```

Please help me to correct this code. I think author is never update course and I am in middle of course. I hope someone help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no more "Switch-AzureMode" since v. 1.0.0 of the Powershell.

The ARM and ASM cmdlets exists together and live together. The ASM cmdlets are with unchanged names, but the ARM cmdlets are all now with **RM** in their name. Like:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount
```

Both the powershell cmdlets can be installed via Web Platform Installer.

More, when on Windows 10, the ARM cmdlets can be installed via PowerShell Gallery using the ofllowing commands (under Aministrative PowerShell console):

```
Install-Module AzureRM
```

Confirm all the questions being asked. Then run the

```
Install-AzureRM
```

Then you are done with the ARM module. Just make sure that your local execution policy is at least "RemoteSigned".

At the end, you will have to edit all your PowerShell scripts to match the new cmdlets and their parameters. Like the `New-AzureResourceGroup` is now `New-AzureRmResourceGroup`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603739.aspx